# What does $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{\zeta(1+\epsilon) + \zeta(1-\epsilon)}{2} =\gamma$ really mean?

Tags: limits, riemann-zeta

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{\zeta(1+\epsilon) + \zeta(1-\epsilon)}{2} =\gamma$$

I am somewhat familiar with the zeta function, but have not taken complex analysis, yet. I saw this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values) and was wondering if someone can explain what the equation means. Does it say that $\zeta(1)$ would equal $\gamma$ if the function didn't go to infinity and negative infinity or something completely different?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x-1} + c,$ which has a singularity (simple pole with residue $1$, if you like) at $x = 1$ and is well-defined everywhere else.

A trivial computation gives $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \dfrac{ f(1+ \epsilon) + f(1 - \epsilon) }{2} = c.$

So the equation you ask about says that in a n.h. of $s = 1$,
the function $\zeta(s)$ looks like $$\dfrac{1}{s-1} + \gamma + \text{higher order terms in } (s-1).$$

Comment: Can you give an example of what higher order terms in s-1?

Comment: @zeta: Dear zeta, There will be a power series in $(s-1)$, of which $\gamma$ is the constant term.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Laurent_series) for the formula for the coefficient of $(s-1)^n$.  Regards,